# How to remove duplicate columns from a dataframe using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

By grouping two columns I made some changes.

I generated a file using python, it resulted in 2 duplicate columns. How to remove duplicate columns from a dataframe?

Comment: Do they have same column name?

Answer (score 23):

It's probably easiest to use a groupby (assuming they have duplicate names too):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   A  B  B
0  a  4  4
1  b  4  4
2  c  4  4

In [12]: df.T.groupby(level=0).first().T
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  a  4
1  b  4
2  c  4
```

If they have different *names* you can `drop_duplicates` on the transpose:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   A  B  C
0  a  4  4
1  b  4  4
2  c  4  4

In [22]: df.T.drop_duplicates().T
Out[22]:
   A  B
0  a  4
1  b  4
2  c  4
```

*Usually `read_csv` will usually ensure they have different names...*

Comment: FYI @Andy, there is a new option in 0.11.1 that controls this ``mangle_dup_cols``; default is TO mangle (e.g. produce unique cols), in 0.12, this will change to leave dups in place

Answer (score 4):

Transposing is a bad idea when working with large DataFrames.  See this answer for a memory efficient alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32961145/759442

Comment: Just a note for others that the best answer is not the accepted one in that thread. Best answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435354/2507197

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I found so far.

```
remove = []
cols = df.columns
for i in range(len(cols)-1):
    v = df[cols[i]].values
    for j in range(i+1,len(cols)):
        if np.array_equal(v,df[cols[j]].values):
            remove.append(cols[j])

df.drop(remove, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

https://www.kaggle.com/kobakhit/santander-customer-satisfaction/0-84-score-with-36-features-only/code

Answer (score 3):

It's already answered here [python pandas remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns). 
Idea is that `df.columns.duplicated()` generates boolean vector where each value says whether it has seen the column before or not. For example, if `df` has columns `["Col1", "Col2", "Col1"]`, then it generates `[False, False, True]`. Let's take inversion of it and call it as `column_selector`.

Using the above vector and using `loc` method of `df` which helps in selecting rows and columns, we can remove the duplicate columns. With `df.loc[:, column_selector]` we can select columns.

```
column_selector = ~df.columns().duplicated()
df = df.loc[:, column_selector]
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it actually drops _only_ the duplicate columns. Most of the other answers I've seen will drop the original _and_ the duplicates.

Comment: `.columns` is not a callable.

Comment: Can you check type on which you are calling, this works only for pandas DataFrame type. You can use `typeof <varname>` to check the type

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an old question, but I recently had this same issue and none of these solutions worked for me, or the looping suggestion seemed a bit overkill. In the end, I simply found the index of the undesirable duplicate column and dropped that column index. So provided you know the index of the column this will work (which you could probably find via debugging or print statements):

```
df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fast solution for dataset without NANs:

```
share = 0.05
dfx = df.sample(int(df.shape[0]*share))
dfx = dfx.T.drop_duplicates().T
df = df[dfx.columns]
```