# How to get a combined look at two different DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I want to show a table which combines two DataFrames with conditional indexing. This works with one DataFrame:

```
room1,weather = pd.read_excel(mypath,sheetnames[0]),pd.read_excel(mypath,sheetnames[2])
selector = (room1.Time>='08:00') & (room1.Time<='18:00')
view     = ['Time','Cooling_plant_sensible_load']
room1[selector][view][:12]
```

which gives me something like this:

```
    Time    Cooling_plant_sensible_load
7   08:00   0.000
8   09:00   0.000
....
16  17:00   0.000
17  18:00   0.000
31  08:00   0.000
```

The `weather` DataFrame has a Series called `Dry_Bulb_Temperature` which I would like to add to the view so it shows like this

```
    Time    Cooling_plant_sensible_load    Dry_Bulb_Temperature
7   08:00   0.000                          18
8   09:00   0.000                          22
....
16  17:00   0.000                          19
17  18:00   0.000                          16
31  08:00   0.000                          12
```

I tried adding:

```
selector2 = (weather.Time>='08:00') & (weather.Time<='18:00')
pd.concat({'room1':room1[selector][view][:12],'wea':weather[selector2]['Dry_bulb_temperature']},axis=1)
```

which gave me a `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_data'`

EDIT:

`weather[selector2]['Dry_bulb_temperature'][:12]` looks like this:

```
major
7        15.3
8        16.0
9        18.0
10       19.9
11       21.9
12       22.9
13       24.0
14       25.0
15       24.8
16       24.5
17       24.3
31       16.2
Name: Dry_bulb_temperature, dtype: float64
```

EDIT2:

The `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_data'` is caused because `weather[selector2]['Dry_bulb_temperature']` is a Series <del>while concat expects a DataFrame</del> which can not be concat-ed with a Dataframe, i.e. concat needs two similar types (previous comment is wrong as pointed out by @Philip below).

So I could combine the room1 DataFrame with the weather DataFrame. Is this the way to go? How do I avoid that the two 'Time' series are duplicated?

I've got a number of room(n) dataframes and was thinking that there might be a way for each to reference the same weather dataset.

Comment: can you show `weather_df[selector2]['Dry_bulb_temperature']`?

Comment: `concat` expects objects the same *type*, not only `DataFrame`s. You can `concat` two `Series`, for example.

Comment: @Philip cheers, that makes a lot of sense, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to do a join (which can merge a DataFrame and a Series on their index):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
    Time  Cooling_plant_sensible_load  Dry_Bulb_Temperature
7  08:00                            0                    18
8  09:00                            0                    22

In [12]: s
Out[12]:
7    15.3
8    16.0
Name: Dry_bulb_temperature, dtype: float64

In [13]: df.join(s)
Out[13]:
    Time  Cooling_plant_sensible_load  Dry_Bulb_Temperature  Dry_bulb_temperature
7  08:00                            0                    18                  15.3
8  09:00                            0                    22                  16.0
```

*See more in the [merging, join and concating section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html).*

Note:

You can create the Series/column using loc, avoiding chaining:

```
s = weather.loc[selector2, 'Dry_bulb_temperature']
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy this looks good too. However it doesn't work in my case since I've got overlapping Series in the dataframes. In the answer below I used `df.T.groupby(level=0).first().T` to remove duplicate columns after concat-ing the dataframes. Being new to pandas, I'm not too sure what's behind these methods though. Cheers.

Comment: Best way is to understand each of the functions in turn. If the example is different it'll help to give a snippet (e.g. the output of df.head().)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is happening in your concat. It might be that you have a field name confused. I see both 'Dry_Bulb_Temperature' and 'Dry_bulb_temperature' in different parts of your question.

Assuming the two dataframes have the same index, I would concat the whole thing, then do your filter:

```
df = pd.concat([room1, weather[['Dry_Bulb_Temperature']]], axis=1)
df[(df['Time'] >= '08:00') & (df['Time'] <= '18:00')]
```

Less code and easier to read.

Comment: Both dataframes have a `Time` series. However I couldn't get your pd.concat to work... it gives me the same `AttributeError` as above. I typed `df = pd.concat([room1, weather['Dry_bulb_temperature']], axis=1)` adding a `]` to your code above

Comment: This concats correctly: `df = pd.concat([room1, weather], axis=1)`. The problem is that `weather['Dry_bulb_temperature]` is a Series object, while concat expects a dataframe...

Comment: ah that's right. updated my answer, but looks like you already have your own!

Comment: You can get a dataframe with one column using [['field']] as above, which gets around your duplicate column problem. Sorry I left you with non-working code before. Bad dev, bad! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got something that works based on @mattexx initial proposal:

```
#pd.concat([room1, weather], axis=1)[selector][view.append('Dry_bulb_temperature')]
df = pd.concat([room1, weather], axis=1)


# Removing duplicate columns based on this link:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938441/how-to-remove-duplicate-columns-from-a-dataframe-using-python-pandas

df = df.T.groupby(level=0).first().T
selector = [(df.Time>='08:00') & (df.Time<='18:00')]
view     = ['Time','Cooling_plant_sensible_load','Dry_bulb_temperature']
df[['Time','Cooling_plant_sensible_load','Dry_bulb_temperature']][(df.Time>='08:00') & (df.Time<='18:00')][:12]
```

which gives:

```
    Time    Cooling_plant_sensible_load     Dry_bulb_temperature
7   08:00   0   15.3
8   09:00   0   16
.......................
17  18:00   0   24.3
31  08:00   0   16.2
```

Not sure if this is the best way to get there, but it works for now. Thanks guys for getting me on the right track.

Comment: You can use `df.loc[(df.Time >= '08:00') & (...), view]` to avoid chaining, and .head(12) to get the last 12 entries. :)