# Panda's DataFrame double transpose changes numeric types to object

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a header and the data for the dataframe from 2 separate locations in excel (both are aligned properly but not adjacent). The header potentially contains many blanks and so I need to discard those headers and the corresponding columns in the data. So my final frame has non-null headers and data corresponding to those headers. The logic below using transposion works but I'm losing the data types upon double transposion - see specific example below -
question
1) any suggestion on how I can achieve it without transposition?
2) is this how transpostion supposed to work? Should it not infer the dtypes again upon second transposition?

```
  In [25]:

hd=pd.DataFrame({0:['num'],
                 1:np.nan,
                 2:['ltr']})
hd
Out[25]:
0   1   2
0    num    NaN  ltr
In [26]:

data=pd.DataFrame({0:np.arange(3),
                 1:['a','b','c'],
                 2:['d','e','f']})
data
Out[26]:
0   1   2
0    0   a   d
1    1   b   e
2    2   c   f
In [27]:

df=data.T[hd.iloc[0].notnull()].T
df.columns=hd.iloc[0].dropna()     
df
Out[27]:
num ltr
0    0   d
1    1   e
2    2   f
In [28]:

df.dtypes
Out[28]:
0
num    object
ltr    object
dtype: object

In [25]:

hd=pd.DataFrame({0:['num'],
                 1:np.nan,
                 2:['ltr']})
hd
Out[25]:
0   1   2
0    num    NaN  ltr
In [26]:

data=pd.DataFrame({0:np.arange(3),
                 1:['a','b','c'],
                 2:['d','e','f']})
data
Out[26]:
0   1   2
0    0   a   d
1    1   b   e
2    2   c   f
In [27]:

df=data.T[hd.iloc[0].notnull()].T
df.columns=hd.iloc[0].dropna()     
df
Out[27]:
num ltr
0    0   d
1    1   e
2    2   f
In [28]:

df.dtypes
Out[28]:
0
num    object
ltr    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: this is as expected, dtypes are column based. you can use ``df.convert_objects()`` if you want to re-infer them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

transposition converted dtypes to `object` when you have mixed-dtypes to begin. this is as expected, dtypes are column based. you can use `df.convert_objects()` if you want to re-infer them.

However, just do this:

```
In [10]: data.loc[:,hd.iloc[0].notnull()]
Out[10]: 
   0  2
0  0  d
1  1  e
2  2  f

In [11]: data.loc[:,hd.iloc[0].notnull()].dtypes
Out[11]: 
0     int64
2    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: `convert_objects` has been deprecated.

Comment: As above, one can now use: pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects