# Concat DataFrame Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to concat the following dataframes:

df1

```
                                price   side timestamp
timestamp           
2016-01-04 00:01:15.631331072   0.7286  2   1451865675631331
2016-01-04 00:01:15.631399936   0.7286  2   1451865675631400
2016-01-04 00:01:15.631860992   0.7286  2   1451865675631861
2016-01-04 00:01:15.631866112   0.7286  2   1451865675631866
```

and:

df2

```
                                bid     bid_size offer  offer_size
timestamp               
2016-01-04 00:00:31.331441920   0.7284  4000000 0.7285  1000000
2016-01-04 00:00:53.631324928   0.7284  4000000 0.7290  4000000
2016-01-04 00:01:03.131234048   0.7284  5000000 0.7286  4000000
2016-01-04 00:01:12.131444992   0.7285  1000000 0.7286  4000000
2016-01-04 00:01:15.631364096   0.7285  4000000 0.7290  4000000
```

With

```
 data = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

But I get the follwing output:

```
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-2e88458f01d7> in <module>()
----> 1 data = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
      2 data = data.fillna(method='pad')
      3 data = data.fillna(method='bfill')
      4 data['timestamp'] =  data.index.values#converting to datetime
      5 data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'])#converting to datetime

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, copy)
    810                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,
    811                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
--> 812                        copy=copy)
    813     return op.get_result()
    814 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy)
    947         self.copy = copy
    948 
--> 949         self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()
    950 
    951     def get_result(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in _get_new_axes(self)
   1013                 if i == self.axis:
   1014                     continue
-> 1015                 new_axes[i] = self._get_comb_axis(i)
   1016         else:
   1017             if len(self.join_axes) != ndim - 1:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in _get_comb_axis(self, i)
   1039                 raise TypeError("Cannot concatenate list of %s" % types)
   1040 
-> 1041         return _get_combined_index(all_indexes, intersect=self.intersect)
   1042 
   1043     def _get_concat_axis(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in _get_combined_index(indexes, intersect)
   6120             index = index.intersection(other)
   6121         return index
-> 6122     union = _union_indexes(indexes)
   6123     return _ensure_index(union)
   6124 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in _union_indexes(indexes)
   6149 
   6150         if hasattr(result, 'union_many'):
-> 6151             return result.union_many(indexes[1:])
   6152         else:
   6153             for other in indexes[1:]:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/index.pyc in union_many(self, others)
    959             else:
    960                 tz = this.tz
--> 961                 this = Index.union(this, other)
    962                 if isinstance(this, DatetimeIndex):
    963                     this.tz = tz

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in union(self, other)
   1553                 result.extend([x for x in other._values if x not in value_set])
   1554         else:
-> 1555             indexer = self.get_indexer(other)
   1556             indexer, = (indexer == -1).nonzero()
   1557 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   1890 
   1891         if not self.is_unique:
-> 1892             raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
   1893                                     ' valued Index objects')
   1894 

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I have removed additional columns and removed duplicates and NA where there could be a conflict - but I simply do not know what's wrong.

Comment: what does `pd.concat` do?

Comment: @gmoshkin it places dataframes together as one dataframe - joined on the axis.

Comment: I have removed the column timestamp from both df1 and df2 and attempted to drop and NA with
df1.dropna() and df2.dropna();
The problem persists....

Comment: @gmoshkin, I am assuming that pd as an alias for pandas: import pandas as pd, and df1 and df2 are pandas DataFrame objects

Comment: try passing `ignore_index=True` to [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Comment: something else to look for, I had a similar error because I had duplicate columns in my dataframe

Comment: Attention, this error could also be caused if there are duplicated columns in one of the dataframes (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/38654)

Comment: @Angel thank you for this comment was very helpful

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`pd.concat` requires that the *indices* be unique. To [remove rows with duplicate indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297689/190597), use

```
df = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'price': [0.7286, 0.7286, 0.7286, 0.7286],
     'side': [2, 2, 2, 2],
     'timestamp': [1451865675631331, 1451865675631400,
                  1451865675631861, 1451865675631866]},
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-1-1', '2000-1-1', '2001-1-1', '2002-1-1']))


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'bid': [0.7284, 0.7284, 0.7284, 0.7285, 0.7285],
     'bid_size': [4000000, 4000000, 5000000, 1000000, 4000000],
     'offer': [0.7285, 0.729, 0.7286, 0.7286, 0.729],
     'offer_size': [1000000, 4000000, 4000000, 4000000, 4000000]},
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-1-1', '2001-1-1', '2002-1-1', '2003-1-1', '2004-1-1']))


df1 = df1.loc[~df1.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
#              price  side         timestamp
# 2000-01-01  0.7286     2  1451865675631331
# 2001-01-01  0.7286     2  1451865675631861
# 2002-01-01  0.7286     2  1451865675631866

df2 = df2.loc[~df2.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
#                bid  bid_size   offer  offer_size
# 2000-01-01  0.7284   4000000  0.7285     1000000
# 2001-01-01  0.7284   4000000  0.7290     4000000
# 2002-01-01  0.7284   5000000  0.7286     4000000
# 2003-01-01  0.7285   1000000  0.7286     4000000
# 2004-01-01  0.7285   4000000  0.7290     4000000

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
print(result)
               bid  bid_size   offer  offer_size   price  side     timestamp
2000-01-01     NaN       NaN     NaN         NaN  0.7286     2  1.451866e+15
2001-01-01     NaN       NaN     NaN         NaN  0.7286     2  1.451866e+15
2002-01-01     NaN       NaN     NaN         NaN  0.7286     2  1.451866e+15
2000-01-01  0.7284   4000000  0.7285     1000000     NaN   NaN           NaN
2001-01-01  0.7284   4000000  0.7290     4000000     NaN   NaN           NaN
2002-01-01  0.7284   5000000  0.7286     4000000     NaN   NaN           NaN
2003-01-01  0.7285   1000000  0.7286     4000000     NaN   NaN           NaN
2004-01-01  0.7285   4000000  0.7290     4000000     NaN   NaN           NaN
```

---

Note there is also `pd.join`, which can join DataFrames based on their indices,
and handle non-unique indices based on the `how` parameter. Rows with duplicate
index are not removed.

```
In [94]: df1.join(df2)
Out[94]: 
             price  side         timestamp     bid  bid_size   offer  \
2000-01-01  0.7286     2  1451865675631331  0.7284   4000000  0.7285   
2000-01-01  0.7286     2  1451865675631400  0.7284   4000000  0.7285   
2001-01-01  0.7286     2  1451865675631861  0.7284   4000000  0.7290   
2002-01-01  0.7286     2  1451865675631866  0.7284   5000000  0.7286   

            offer_size  
2000-01-01     1000000  
2000-01-01     1000000  
2001-01-01     4000000  
2002-01-01     4000000  

In [95]: df1.join(df2, how='outer')
Out[95]: 
             price  side     timestamp     bid  bid_size   offer  offer_size
2000-01-01  0.7286     2  1.451866e+15  0.7284   4000000  0.7285     1000000
2000-01-01  0.7286     2  1.451866e+15  0.7284   4000000  0.7285     1000000
2001-01-01  0.7286     2  1.451866e+15  0.7284   4000000  0.7290     4000000
2002-01-01  0.7286     2  1.451866e+15  0.7284   5000000  0.7286     4000000
2003-01-01     NaN   NaN           NaN  0.7285   1000000  0.7286     4000000
2004-01-01     NaN   NaN           NaN  0.7285   4000000  0.7290     4000000
```

Answer (score 130):

## Duplicated column names!

In my case the problem was because I had duplicated column names.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435354/3362993 for code to remove duplicated column names

Comment: This is a nice hint! In my case, I use `df1 = df1.append(df2)` to concatenate. However, 2 out of the 16 columns are different, causing the issue.

Comment: I think the error usually occurs with column names, because mostly people will concatenate over the row-axis (i.e. `axis=0` or unspecified). In this case the index must be unique `axis=1`. With `axis=0` the indices don't need to be unique, but the columns do. This is because otherwise it's ambiguous how to align the duplicate columns among different dataframes. In the case of `axis=1` the columns can have duplicates, but the indices must be unique with the same reasoning, e.g. which rows should be aligned across dataframes.

Comment: This happened in my case because I converted all column names to upper case, making two of them the same.

Comment: Duplicated column names  + Trying to merge dataframes with different column length example:

df1: columns -> ["A","B"]
df2: columns ->["A", "A", "B", C]

pd.concat([df1, df2])

Will show this error.

To solve it, rename the duplicated column names

Comment: The error, `InvalidIndexError`, should be changed to something more explanatory.

Answer (score 107):

You can mitigate this error without having to change your data or remove duplicates. Just create a new index with [DataFrame.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

The old index is kept as a column in your dataframe, but if you don't need it you can do:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Some prefer:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: This should be marked asd the right answer, since it solves the problem without loosing information. Not always duplicate records are wrong on the datasets.

Comment: I still get the error, even I perform this transformation on the dataset

Comment: What if this does not work?
`pd.concat([df_1a.reset_index()[common_features], df_1b.reset_index()[common_features]])`
> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: In my case, I had a duplicated column (hope it helps someone else!).

Comment: For me I need to change a series from an object to a datetime. On one series it works fine but on the other 3 i get the above errors. So my questions is why does my df allow me to do it for one series but not another?

Comment: @João Thank you so much for that sanity check. I, too, had a duplicated column that I didn't realize was there. Removing it fixed my problem.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that usually this error occurs with **duplicate columns**, rather than indices, since mostly `pd.concat` is used with `axis=0` (as per my guess) instead of `axis=1`. of course, both are simply the transposed version Of each other. See @Angel 's answer.

Comment: I did not have duplicated columns, nor did I have duplicated indicies. However, I noticed I was using `sort_values` on the dataframes which was left over from some previous functionality. Removing sorting (which was unnecessary) solved the problem for me. This is quite odd however because I don't think it should be a problem.

Answer (score 27):

This post comes up top when you search for the error but the answers are not complete, so let me add mine. There is another reason this error can happen: If you have duplicate columns in your data frames, you will not be able to concatenate and raise this. In fact, even in the original question there are two columns called `timestamp`. So it will be better to check if `len(df.columns) == len(set(df.columns))` for all the data frames you are trying to concatenate.

Comment: dupe columns was the problem for me.

Comment: Or you can use: assert df.columns.is_unique, df.loc[:,df.columns.duplicated()]  : this asserts that the columns are unique and shows the duplicate columns if they are not unique

Answer (score 8):

As a complement of Nicholas Morley's answer, when you find even this not works:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

You should check whether the columns are unique. When they are not, even reseting index not works. Duplicated columns should be removed first to make it works.

Answer (score 4):

This happens also when you have duplicates in the columns names.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have duplicated columns. Before concatenating drop duplicated columns in each DataFrame as follows:

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Same Indices Between the Two DFs

Another reason for this issue might be that `df1` and `df2` might have the same indices, between each other. For example, both the dfs might have the same index `idx1`.

To check if this is the issue, you can see if the following outputs not an empty list:

```
print([org_name for org_name in cum_df.index if org_name in df_from_2002.index])
```

My suggested solution then would be to rename the indices (so `df1` would keep having `idx1` and you would change `idx1` to `idx2` in `df2`) and after concatenating (`df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])`), combine the two indices (in case you need to get the sum of them) with this code:

```
df1.iloc[idx1] = df1.iloc[[idx1, idx2]].sum()
```

and then remove `idx2`:

```
df1.drop([idx2], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

### The indexes of your two dataframes don't match.

When pandas is performing concat operation horizontally (axis=1) it tries to find rows with same indexes and join them horizontally. *So row with index 1 from df1 will be matched with row with index 1.* Therefore reset index in either one of them or both if both have troubled indexes.

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2], axis=1)
```

or

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True), axis=1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I was trying to concat two dataframes that have *duplicated column names!*

Let's say that I want to remove the first duplicated column:

```
duplicated_column = 'column'

df_tmp = df[duplicated_column].T
df_tmp = df_tmp.iloc[1: , :]

df = df.drop([duplicated_column], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, df_tmp.T], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was duplicate column labels, just as many others here mentioned it.
To keep only the first column for duplicates I used below:

```
df=df.T[~df.T.index.duplicated(keep='first')].T
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers here helped but concat worked fine for me in some cases even where duplicate columns were present. However, in some cases it didn't work and raised the `InvalidIndexError`.

It turned out that it works fine if order of duplicate columns is same but raises an error if order of duplicate columns is different.

Example where it works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5, 6, 7], 'c': [9, 10, 11]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12], 'b': [13], 'c': [14]})
df.rename(columns={
    'c': 'b'
}, inplace=True)
df1.rename(columns={
    'c': 'b'
}, inplace=True)
print(pd.concat([df, df1]))

Output:
    a   b   b
0   1   5   9
1   2   6  10
2   3   7  11
0  12  13  14
```

Example where it doesn't work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'b': [1, 2, 3], 'a': [5, 6, 7], 'c': [9, 10, 11]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12], 'b': [13], 'c': [14]})
df.rename(columns={
    'c': 'b'
}, inplace=True)
df1.rename(columns={
    'c': 'b'
}, inplace=True)
print(pd.concat([df, df1]))

Output:
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely 
valued Index objects
```

Answer (score 0):

below solution would work if you are concat is using axis=0, which means you want to append rows not columns

reason : one or both of your dataframes might have duplicate columns
df1 columns could be A, B, C , C
df2 columns could be B, D

in this case A has duplicate column C, and for this reason you might get this error. Drop one of the C column in df1 and hopefully issue will be resolved

df1['C'].is_unique

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same with me, but then I noticed that my index (datetime) has different last dates. When I fixed the date using the same timeframe interval for both dataframes the `pd.concat()` worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

best solution from this page:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/merging.html

> ```
> df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join_axes=[df1.index])
> ```

Comment: `TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'`