# python pandas merge multiple csv InvalidIndexError

Tags: python, csv

The purpose of this code is to merge 900 csv files into one single file with unified reshaped date time.

Each file has 5 columns `['DateTime', Actual, Consensus, Previous, Revised]` The same column names for every file.

The files are not equal in rows number and for the time steps, for the 900 source files there is 4500 columns in one merged file.
here is some sample data:

https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/b2ba798d-1490-4a1b-9a7d-174eeb414926
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/7a515013-5178-468b-b14b-19351b984e33
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/7b280ce6-08b3-4b5a-83a7-1a6014d4bab7
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/08f4deaa-a536-4746-9983-2400a2db4722
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/4bd3c8bc-c6d4-4f02-bed8-28d0caae7beb
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/86ab275d-83f3-4760-a9f3-3a51f842029f
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/6b0f63fa-277c-458c-b7d1-3c0f2963deaa
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/69921d2c-072f-47df-ba4f-3cbf0efaa293
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/4e7f2b96-19aa-46f9-8f4a-403f2334fadb
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/a0d1effc-9698-477f-9da6-41db2f7a1dbe
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/7a262107-aa0b-478c-a0c4-49b2a8589738
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/42ead1f1-30c2-459d-84ed-4a2b0deaba8a
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/015035d6-7dfe-4bb0-a138-5362dbcdf309
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/30d4dcf7-be62-4401-8cdd-96d1a8a989da
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/dad82d0d-0561-4275-bdea-56f8e3709581
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/d080d54a-58ac-49fc-9463-589260fdc6de
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/70d803d1-04e2-496b-a565-5fe08e89cc48
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/04e37486-f4aa-4a54-875b-62fae3b62486
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/0205d838-1106-4d7d-abdd-692f33fb5686
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/727dc859-0e7d-4209-8f28-70acb2ea2d61
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/14dce315-f073-4ffb-9205-95c78e42929c
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/3a35946f-7a82-4e4f-9582-9c61676eecb3
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/98bb2374-b9f9-46ae-93e3-9f7e8a4391c1
https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/event/a5d475bb-27fa-4a82-90ba-9fc271c5b9bd

Here is the code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('E:\\Business\\Economic Indicators')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
       for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('csv')]

finaldf = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer').sort_index(ascending=False)
finaldf = finaldf.loc[~finaldf.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

print(finaldf.head())
finaldf.to_csv('finaldf.csv')
```

but i've got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/Tutorial/Driver/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/adaa.py", line 8, in <module>
    finaldf = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer').sort_index(ascending=False)
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 212, in concat
    copy=copy)
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 363, in __init__
    self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 430, in _get_new_axes
    new_axes[i] = self._get_comb_axis(i)
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 450, in _get_comb_axis
    intersect=self.intersect)
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py", line 42, in _get_objs_combined_axis
    return _get_combined_index(obs_idxes, intersect=intersect)
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py", line 57, in _get_combined_index
    union = _union_indexes(indexes)
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py", line 84, in _union_indexes
    return result.union_many(indexes[1:])
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 1054, in union_many
    this = Index.union(this, other)
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2239, in union
    indexer = self.get_indexer(other)
File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2687, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: @SCB thanks for edit

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084071/concat-dataframe-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objects).

Comment: @Cleb same error after edit

Comment: I did not read the things in detail but it looks like in the other answer, the `duplicated` part is ran before the `concat`. Have you tried that? Check also the `reset_index` solution.

Comment: @Cleb it is in the original code

Comment: Where? You concat first and the run the `duplicate` stuff afterwards; in the other solution it is the other way round if I see that correctly.

Comment: I can’t do his way because I opened all files in one line of code. But In his way, he opened each file at a time, I can’t do that its around 900 files

Comment: You could just run another list comprehension where you use the `duplicate` or `reset_index` part, I think.

Comment: sorry but your idea is not clear for me, can you give me an example to make me understand it right. I mean it is 900 files each file has 5 columns, so I can't figure out the (map, filter…etc.) arguments to make right.

Comment: It is a bit tricky as you don't provide any data :) I guess something like `dfs = [dfi.loc[~dfi.index.duplicated(keep='first')] for dfi in dfs]` prior to `concat` could(!) work. As written, difficult to say without any data.

Comment: i add some data in the post

Comment: still no answer

Comment: As one can still not simply copy-and-paste your data. People here are not paid so it is up to the person who asks the question to make it as easy as possible to answer it. Did you try my line from above? Could you not just copy three of the dataframes above and post them here so that one can just copy them?