# Pandas find closest value from timestamp index error

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have an error while trying to find a value in a pandas df from a timestamp.
My df has a timestamp index.

My timestamp is :

```
time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sub_data_2[0, itime])
print(time)
2021-06-29 09:53:08.805039
```

My df index looks like this :

```
print(df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2021-06-30 08:45:43', '2021-06-30 08:45:45',
               '2021-06-30 08:45:46', '2021-06-30 08:45:47',
               '2021-06-30 08:45:48', '2021-06-30 08:45:50',
               '2021-06-30 08:45:51', '2021-06-30 08:45:52',
               '2021-06-30 08:45:53', '2021-06-30 08:45:54',
               ...
               '2021-06-28 16:34:22', '2021-06-28 16:34:23',
               '2021-06-28 16:34:24', '2021-06-28 16:34:25',
               '2021-06-28 16:34:26', '2021-06-28 16:34:27',
               '2021-06-28 16:34:28', '2021-06-28 16:34:29',
               '2021-06-28 16:34:30', '2021-06-28 16:34:31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='T', length=54143, freq=None)
```

Using the index.get_loc function :

```
index = df.index.get_loc(time, method='nearest')
```

The error is :

```
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I see this error can come from the concatenation of dataframes with conflicts of indexes but it is not the case here.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two problems : duplicates and sort the timestamp index.

```
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove duplicates from the index first. This is already answered here - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084071/concat-dataframe-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the duplicated index like this:

```
df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Comment: @KarlMontalban, please elaborate. This should not solve it, it should help you find the duplicates which are responsible for the error.

Comment: Finally I had to remove duplicates and sort my index. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @KarlMontalban, Glad I could help, if the answer was helpful, please consider to upvote and accept it. It helps future readers and gives me a few points, for you as well when acepting the answer.