# InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects when using pd.to_datetime on non NAN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a `df` which contains order data:

```
date        order_id        cost        category
2021-07-12  10              50          A
2021-07-12  10              57          B
2021-08-15  15              76          C
2022-01-11  5               67          C
```

In reality I have about 40 columns, I get an error when I try to run:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

I've read many answers and most of them say it has to do with `NaN` values or duplicate columns. So I checked:

```
sum(df.date.isna())
# 0

len(df.columns) == len(set(df.columns))
# True
```

So I don't have 'NaN' values and I have no duplicates. The other strange thing is that if I close VSCode and restart everything sometimes this error does not appear for the same dataset, so is there some kind of bug? This time I tried restarting everything multiple times but the error persists.

I checked this answer and others:

[first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084071/concat-dataframe-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objects) and tried `df = df.reset_index()` which did not help. So I am stuck and unable to find the reason for this error which seems really strange.

**Update**

I tried `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` which returns the same error.

I checked the following:

```
{type(x) for x in df.date}

# {datetime.date, pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp, str}
```

Which could be the problem.

Comment: Can you try `df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` ?

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Try `f['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert values to strings:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str))
```