# Python: Search for values from one csv file to another and get values from other columns

Tags: python, excel, csv

I want to retrieve the **Price** and **Stocks** from bottom csv file and insert it in the top csv file.

I can read both csv files and have two dictionaries, let's say **top_dic** & **bottom_dic**

How do go through both dictionaries, take **MPN** values from **top_dic**, find the values in **bottom_dic**, extract the **stock** and **price** for the corresponding products and insert these values in top csv?

[image]

Comment: This would be easier if you used pandas. Read each CSV into a dataframe, then merge them according to the relationship you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your two files look more like an [*Excel spreadsheet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#XML_Spreadsheet) than a [*csv*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

But anyways, if [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) is an option, you can make a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the targeted values :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx") # or pd.read_csv("file1.csv", sep=",")
df2 = pd.read_excel("file2.xlsx") # or pd.read_csv("file2.csv", sep=",")

d_map = { # Origin (file1) <> Target (file2)
    "Current Price": "Price", "Stocks": "Stock"
}

df1 = (
    df1.assign(**{o: df1["MPN"].map(
        df2.set_index("Product Code")[t]) for (o,t) in d_map.items()})
)
    
df1.to_excel("file1.xlsx", index=False) # or `to_csv`
# NB : In both cases, the original file1 will be overwritten
```

Comment: Looks like clean code and may work but I'm getting this error "pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" at line "df2.set_index("Product Code")[t]) for (o,t) in d_map.items()})"

Comment: It means that the `Product Code` column in your second file hold duplicates. In other words, a product code can have more than one stock/price (*which is not what your images show*).

Comment: Yes, it may be possible as I've over 10k rows. Is there a solution to handle the duplicates?

Comment: There are solutions but they depend on your expected behaviour/output. Maybe, you should update your question with a meaningful examples *as text* so I can copy/paste.

Comment: The relevant columns are product codes and prices which we are already reading. There is a chance that product codes can be duplicate in the file. That is it. Rest of columns shouldn't matter really? I searched for the error and found discussion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084071/concat-dataframe-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objects but that doesn't help me

Comment: The error cause is explained in my previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77137976/python-search-for-values-from-one-csv-file-to-another-and-get-values-from-other/77138079?noredirect=1#comment136012743_77138079). Without a reproducible example of your two files **as texts** that trigger the error and showing the exact matching expected output, I'm afraid I can't help you.