# `mp.pool.ThreadPool` fails when `mp.pool` works normally

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm using the multiprocessing python library to run in parallel feature selection for a machine learning problem. This function accepts as input a pandas dataframe and returns some figures.

When I execute this function using `mp.pool.map()` everything runs smoothly. However, if I substitute it with `mp.pool.ThreadPool.map()` it fails with this error:

`AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
 # manager items: 15, # tot_items: 20`.

Strangely, I was running the `ThreadPool` code normally till yesterday. Then, I tried to re-run it and started getting these errors. I need `ThreadPool` since this is an IO bound job and it was running much faster compared to `pool`.

**EDIT**: 
The code goes like that (python 2.7):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd (version 0.22.0)

def main_functionality(df, params):
    df = df[params['feature']]
    #Run 5-fold cross-validation
        data_df = pd.DataFrame(....)
        pred_df = pred_df.append(data_df)
    return statistics from pred_df

def a_function(df_init, feature, params_init):

    params = dict(params_init)
    df = df_init.copy()

    params['feature'] = feature
    try:
        results = main_functionality(df, params)
    except:
        results = (0,0,0)

    return results

def b_function(df, features):
    pool = mp.pool.ThreadPool(4)
    params = {...}
    results = pool.map(a_function,(df, feature, params) for f in features))

    results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    results_df.to_csv(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = read.csv(...) # A big CSV file (i.e. few GBs)
    features = [i for i in df.columns if i ....]

    b_function(df, features)
```

Comment: Do you have an assert somewhere in your code? Can you post some part of it?

Comment: that error message is from pandas not multiprocessing.

Comment: Your question seems like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137952/pandas-concat-failing   It probably has nothing to do with `ThreadPool` vs multiprocessing but simply you changed data and now pandas is raising that error.

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn Added some pseudocode above.

Comment: Change your **pseudocode** to [mcve]

Comment: @stovfl Thanks, I wish I knew which lines of code produce the problem so I could provide a minimal example. Unfortunately, I do not.

Comment: Are you aware about: **This module is OBSOLETE. Please DO NOT USE IT FOR NEW PROJECTS!** [threadpool 1.3.2](https://pypi.org/project/threadpool/)

Comment: @stovfl I'm using that module. I'm using `multiprocessing` library.

Comment: Do you mean: "I don't use package threadpool"?. **Edit your Question** and tell which **python version** and prepend your `import` lines to your code.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. I'm NOT using `threadpool` package. I updated the pseudocode with pandas version and python version.

Comment: code looks a bit like you could modify the same `pred_df` from multiple threads.  this might randomly break depending on how threads get scheduled.  using processes should be fine as each process will have its own copy of the whole object

Comment: @SamMason You were right. I had to add the first two lines in `a_function()` so that each thread is now working on its own copy of the params dict and the pandas dataframe.

Comment: Everything now working properly.