# AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items # manager items: 6004, # tot_items: 6005

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteritems

My code:

```
for column_name, column_data in summary_words.iteritems():
    if column_name != "summary" and column_name != "text" and column_name != "score" and column_name != "helpfulness":
        summary_words[column_name] = summary_words["summary"].str.count(column_name)
```

where summary_words is a pandas dataframe, and "summary" is a column in that dataframe. When I run the code I get this error:

> AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
>   manager items: 6004, # tot_items: 6005

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

```
great   my  This    love    you best    and will    favorite    watch   ... step    succeeds    judge   (who    strictly    things, helpfulness score   summary text
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.0   3   "There Is So Much Darkness Now ~ Come For The ...   Synopsis: On the daily trek from Juarez, Mexic...
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.0   3   Worthwhile and Important Story Hampered by Poo...   THE VIRGIN OF JUAREZ is based on true events s...
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 80.0    5   This movie needed to be made.   The scenes in this film can be very disquietin...
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.0   3   distantly based on a real tragedy   THE VIRGIN OF JUAREZ (2006)<br />directed by K...
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.0   3   "What's going on down in Juarez and shining a ...   Informationally, this SHOWTIME original is ess...
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
99995   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0 5   A Great Collection! Gave this for a friends birthday and she LOVES...
99996   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0 5   TOOOOO FUNNY    I had not seen the MP guys for years. I have o...
99997   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0 5   monty python    this is the best flying circus that monty pyth...
99998   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0 5   Python at its best and purest!  If you are a serious Monty Python fan, then th...
99999   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0 5   Monty Python 16 DVD set I got this as a Christmas gift for my son - th...
```

Comment: Hey @Jack, it is not possible to reproduce without sample data. Could you provide an example that reproduces the issue? It is fine to copy/paste the text form of a `pd.DataFrame` and it can be restored elsewhere with `pd.read_clipboard()`. See here for more detail on how to make it as easy as possible for us to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I added a link with sample data from the dataframe

Comment: Hey @Jack, an image is not sufficient. It should be possible to copy/paste the data for local testing. Please see the thread I linked above about how to best share data.

Comment: Will copying and pasting the data from the Jupyter notebook I'm working on be fine.

Comment: I added copy and pastable data to the post. Now can you answer it?

Comment: Unfortunately that data does not work for `pb.read_clipboard()`. I know it may be tricky, but do you think you could make a smaller example?

Comment: By the way, have you reviewed this SO post on the same error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137952/pandas-concat-failing/42385623 It seems like this error is related to duplicate column names. Perhaps you have `summary` or `helpfulness` as words in your vocabulary, and those are colliding with your specialized use of those same words?

Comment: Okay I will post this as an answer. Let me know if you need any additional clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very likely that your special-use keywords, like `summary` and `helpfulness`, are colliding with words in the vocabulary you are analyzing.

You should be able to check this pretty quickly by looking at the lengths:

```py
len(summary_words.columns)
len(set(summary_words.columns))
```

See this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137952/pandas-concat-failing/42385623) for additional detail on the multiple columns issue, in the context of a `pd.concat`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quite similar problem. the error was: "Number of manager items must equal union of block items # manager items: 11, # tot_items: 9"
it was because the columns I inserted were more than those really existed in my dataset.
in other words, I had removed 2 columns before. so the error was logical since there were only 9 columns left.