# feature_names must be unique - Xgboost

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost, sklearn-pandas

I am running the xgboost model for a very sparse matrix.

I am getting this error. ValueError: feature_names must be unique

How can I deal with this?

This is my code.

```
  yprob = bst.predict(xgb.DMatrix(test_df))[:,1]
```

Answer (score 13):

According the the [`xgboost` source code documentation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/179b384e396a8897340c080d9af79af215c1caaf/python-package/xgboost/core.py), this error only occurs in [one place](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/179b384e396a8897340c080d9af79af215c1caaf/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L583) - in a `DMatrix` internal function.  Here's the source code excerpt:

```
if len(feature_names) != len(set(feature_names)):
    raise ValueError('feature_names must be unique')
```

So, the error text is pretty literal here; your `test_df` has at least one duplicate feature/column name.

You've tagged `pandas` on this post; that suggests `test_df` is a Pandas `DataFrame`.  In this case, `DMatrix` [literally runs `df.columns`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/179b384e396a8897340c080d9af79af215c1caaf/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L168) to extract `feature_names`.  Check your `test_df` for repeat column names, remove or rename them, and then try `DMatrix()` again.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the problem is indeed that columns are duplicated, the following line should solve your problem:

```
test_df = test_df.loc[:,~test_df.columns.duplicated()]
```

Source:    [python pandas remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns)

This line should identify which columns are duplicated:

```
duplicate_columns = test_df.columns[test_df.columns.duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way around this can be to use column names that are unique while preparing the data and then it should work out.

Answer (score 0):

I converted to them to np.array(df). My problem was solved