# How to reduce dimension of the binary data?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, pca

I have a dataframe with binary data and I know there are dependency across columns. I want to remove dependent columns and only want to remain with independent columns. An example input is as follows:

```
Test ,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P
test1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1
test2,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1
test3,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1
test4,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1
test5,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1
```

Here we see, `(A,B,C,G,M), (D), (E,F), (H,I,J,K,L,P) and (N, O)` are the columns that groups having same values or dependent columns. Finally I want to get the following columns:

`Test,A,D,E,H,N
test1,0,0,0,1,1
test2,1,0,1,1,0
test3,1,0,1,1,0
test4,1,1,0,1,0
test5,1,1,0,1,0`

I am trying to use PCA in python but not able to achieve it. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

**EDIT:** Here is the example code I am using

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df = pd.read_csv("TestInput.csv")
print(df)
pca = PCA()

#Remote the header and the row names
numDf = df.iloc[:,1:]
print(pca.fit(numDf))
T=pca.transform(numDf)

print("Number of unique columns are:", T.shape[1])
print(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need not use PCA for this, because the values indicate clearly that the columns are very similiar.. Why not compare the values in the columns and drop duplicate ones?

Comment: @AnandCU In this example, the number of columns are limited but in my original problem I have 100000 columns and 100000 rows. So, doing a similarity test on such a big dataframe will take time.

Comment: Have you tried PCA? Where are you stuck? Also check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/a/14985695/5026636 . Give it a try.

Comment: @AnandCU Added the code I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048530/how-to-reduce-dimension-of-the-binary-data#comment81044138_47048530) into an answer, find and drop duplicate columns with `drop_duplicates`.

```
df = df.set_index('Test')
df.T.drop_duplicates(keep='first').T

       A  D  E  H  N
Test                
test1  0  0  0  1  1
test2  1  0  1  1  0
test3  1  0  1  1  0
test4  1  1  0  1  0
test5  1  1  0  1  0
```