# How to show all columns' names on a large pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consist of hundreds of columns, and I need to see all column names.

What I did:

```
In[37]:
data_all2.columns
```

The output is:

```
Out[37]:
Index(['customer_id', 'incoming', 'outgoing', 'awan', 'bank', 'family', 'food',
       'government', 'internet', 'isipulsa',
       ...
       'overdue_3months_feature78', 'overdue_3months_feature79',
       'overdue_3months_feature80', 'overdue_3months_feature81',
       'overdue_3months_feature82', 'overdue_3months_feature83',
       'overdue_3months_feature84', 'overdue_3months_feature85',
       'overdue_3months_feature86', 'loan_overdue_3months_total_y'],
      dtype='object', length=102)
```

How do I show *all* columns, instead of a truncated list?

Comment: This is what I often use: `import pandas as pd; pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000); pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000); pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)`. The benefit is that *not only* all colums are well displayed, but also the printed rows can be larger than the usual ~100 characters limit.

Answer (score 617, accepted):

You can globally set printing options. I think this should work:

**Method 1:**

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

**Method 2:**

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
```

This will allow you to see all column names & rows when you are doing `.head()`. None of the column name will be truncated.

---

If you just want to see the column names you can do:

```
print(df.columns.tolist())
```

Comment: Method 2 worked where Method 1 didn't. Might be related to the answer below about context. posted by nico

Comment: If you want to prevent wrapping of the output then you need to set the `display.width` option to a very large number. For example: `pd.set_option('display.width', 9999)`

Answer (score 76):

To obtain all the column names of a DataFrame, `df_data` in this example, you just need to use the command `df_data.columns.values`.
This will show you a list with all the Column names of your Dataframe

**Code:**

```
df_data=pd.read_csv('../input/data.csv')
print(df_data.columns.values)
```

**Output:**

```
['PassengerId' 'Survived' 'Pclass' 'Name' 'Sex' 'Age' 'SibSp' 'Parch' 'Ticket' 'Fare' 'Cabin' 'Embarked']
```

Answer (score 42):

This will do the trick. Note the use of `display()` instead of print.

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 5, 'display.max_columns', None): 
    display(my_df)
```

EDIT:

The use of `display` is required because `pd.option_context` settings only apply to `display` and not to `print`.

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer caused my column names to wrap around.  To show all the column names without wrapping, set both display.max_columns and the [display.width](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html):

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pandas.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

Answer (score 18):

In the interactive console, it's easy to do:

```
data_all2.columns.tolist()
```

Or this within a script:

```
print(data_all2.columns.tolist())
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to see the all columns in Pandas df.head(), then use this snippet before running your code. All column data will be visible.

```
pd.pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

After this create your dataframe, and try this.

```
df.head()
```

It will print the all columns instead of showing "...." in larger dataset.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me was the following:

```
pd.options.display.max_seq_items = None
```

You can also set it to an integer larger than your number of columns.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way I've found is just

```
list(df.columns)
```

Personally I wouldn't want to change the globals, it's not that often I want to see all the columns names.

Comment: This is why you can use a context manager so that you can limit the scope.

Comment: When you limit the scope you can run into strange issues. I found `option_context` works while `set_option` doesn't. They have their uses in many cases but for something this rudimentary I prefer a simple, easy to remember solution.

Answer (score 5):

Not a conventional answer, but I guess you could transpose the dataframe to look at the rows instead of the columns. I use this because I find looking at rows more 'intuitional' than looking at columns:

```
data_all2.T
```

This should let you view all the rows. *This action is not permanent*, it just lets you view the transposed version of the dataframe.

If the rows are still truncated, just use `print(data_all2.T)` to view everything.

Comment: _Not a conventional answer, but I guess you could transpose the dataframe to look at the rows instead of the columns._ All they want is the column names, no? _If the rows are still truncated, just use print(data_all2.T) to view everything._ How would printing the result solve the issue? Are you not already printing it anyway?

Answer (score 4):

you can try this

```
pd.pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

df.columns.values

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer was already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54421030/18145256).

Answer (score 3):

To get all column name you can iterate over the `data_all2.columns`.

```
columns = data_all2.columns
for col in columns:
    print col
```

You will get all column names.
Or you can store all column names to another list variable and then print list.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
df.info(show_counts=True)
```

It will show all the columns. Setting `show_counts` to `True` shows the count of `not_null` data.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in df2.columns.tolist():
  print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution would be to convert it to a string

```
print('\t'.join(data_all2.columns))
```

would cause all of them to be printed out separated by tabs
Of course, do note that with 102 names, all of them rather long, this will be a bit hard to read through

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a repetition but I always end up copy pasting and modifying YOLO's answer:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.head(None)
```

In this way, you can see all things with a format data frame.
You need to write

```
data_all2.head(None)
```

Answer (score 2):

My go-to function to print every column on my console is:

```
pandas.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see all the columns you can do something of this sort as a quick fix

```
cols = data_all2.columns
```

now cols will behave as a iterative variable that can be indexed. for example

```
cols[11:20]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had lots of duplicate column names, and once I ran

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

I was able to see the full list of columns

Credit:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435354/5846417

Answer (score 1):

I may be off the mark but I came to this thread with the same type of problem I found this is the simple answer if you want to see everything in a long list and the index.

This is what I use in Spyder:

```
print(df.info())
```

or this be what is needed in Jupyter:

```
df.info()
```

Answer (score 1):

"df.types" gets all the columns of data frame 'df' as output as rows, and as a side bonus, you will also get the data type.

Comment: Your answer does not address the OP's question of how to display the **full** list of columns.  With `df.dtypes` you will still get a truncated list, unless you take one of the steps described in the other answers.