# Show all colums of a pandas-dataframe in ".describe()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am stuck here, but I it's a two part question. Looking at the output of .describe(include = 'all'), not all columns are showing; how do I get all columns to show?

This is a common problem that I have all of the time with Spyder, how to have all columns to show in Console. Any help is appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns

mydata = pd.read_csv("E:\ho11.csv")
mydata.head()
print(mydata.describe(include="all", exclude = None))

mydata.info()
```

OUTPUT:

- [code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV2gH.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show all of columns name on pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188960/how-to-show-all-of-columns-name-on-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Solution

You could use either of the following methods:

**Method-1**:

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188960/how-to-show-all-of-columns-name-on-pandas-dataframe/49189503)

```py
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
```

**Method-2**:

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188960/how-to-show-all-of-columns-name-on-pandas-dataframe/49189503)

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

# to reset this
pd.reset_option('display.max_columns')
```

**Method-3**:

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188960/how-to-show-all-of-columns-name-on-pandas-dataframe/49189503)

```py
# assuming df is your dataframe
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', df.columns.size)

# to reset this
pd.reset_option('display.max_columns')
```

**Method-4**:

[source](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-show-all-columns-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe-c49d4507fcf)

```py
# assuming df is your dataframe
pd.set_option('max_columns', df.columns.size)

# to reset this
pd.reset_option('max_columns')
```

### To not wrap the output into multiple lines do this

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

```py
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```

### References

I will recommend you to explore the following resources for more details and examples.

1. [How to show all of columns name on pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188960/how-to-show-all-of-columns-name-on-pandas-dataframe/49189503)
2. [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188960/how-to-show-all-of-columns-name-on-pandas-dataframe/49189503)
3. [How to show all columns / rows of a Pandas Dataframe?](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-show-all-columns-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe-c49d4507fcf)

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Spyder the easiest thing to do would be:

```
myview = mydata.describe()
```

Then you can inspect 'myview' in the variable explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Using pd.set_option listed column names in the console truncated in the middle with three dots.

To print a full list of the column names from a dataframe to the console in Spyder:

```
list(df.columns)
```