# How to write a "big" data frame in a txt file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write in Python a code which allows me to have a "big" Dataframe (using Pandas) in an text file (constituted from 8 array).
My problem is that if the DataFrame has more than 60 columns, it´s not showed completely and is also with continuity points in the text file. I added a screen shot.

Here is my code:

```
TemperatureStagnation = []
PressureStagnation = []
Pressure = []
AlphaAngle = []
GammaAnlge = []
TurbulentDissipationRate = []
TurbulentEnergyKinketik = []

for i in range(1,len(Machnumber)+1):
  Tt = 240 #in K - Isotherm Profile
  p = 36630 #in Pa - isobar 
  pt = p * (1+((kappa-1)/2)*Machnumber[i-1]**2)**(kappa/(kappa-1)) #isentropic Flow relation
  Alpha = 0.000 #No deviation
  Gamma = 0.000 #No deviation
  TDR = 0.000 #Zero Turbulent Dissipation Rate
  TEK = 0.000 #Zero Turbulent Energy Kinetic
  
  TemperatureStagnation.append(Tt)
  PressureStagnation.append(pt)
  Pressure.append(p)
  AlphaAngle.append(Alpha)
  GammaAnlge.append(Gamma)
  TurbulentDissipationRate.append(TDR)
  TurbulentEnergyKinketik.append(TEK)
  
Header = "TRACE_Input_Wall"
Input = pd.DataFrame({'Rr':Rr,'Ma':Machnumber,'Tt':TemperatureStagnation,'pt':PressureStagnation,'p':Pressure,'Alpha':AlphaAngle,'Gamma':GammaAnlge,'TDR':TurbulentDissipationRate,'TEK':TurbulentEnergyKinketik}) 
print (Input)
f= open("TRACE_Input_Wall.txt","w+")
file = open("TRACE_Input_Wall.txt","r+")
file.truncate(0)
file.close()
print (Header,file=open("TRACE_Input_Profiles_Mourad.txt", "a"))
print (Input,file=open("TRACE_Input_Profiles_Mourad.txt", "a"))
print ("Output successful!")
```

Anyone has a better idea? (pandas and numpy are already imported in my or[image]iginal code.)

Comment: why not using df.to_txt() method?

Answer (score 0):

As Felício commented, you could just use

```
np.savetxt('/path/to/file.txt', Input.values)
```

for saving the data in a txt file (for more info see [numpy.savetxt.html](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)). Definitely working for >60 columns, but the header needs to be added separately.

Alternatively you could use

```
Input.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
```

to save the data in a csv file (see [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for more options).

This question might help, if you want to see all data frame columns in Spyder: [python-spyder-show-all-colums-of-a-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455605/python-spyder-show-all-colums-of-a-pandas-dataframe-in-describe)

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In Spyder,

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```

seems to work quite well. Paste it into your console, and then call `Input`. Drag the console so that it fills the screen, and the DataFrame should expand with it (which is not the default behaviour). It may be the case that your DataFrame is way too large for this, in which case the txt file answers are good, but personally I would run:

```
Input.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
```

and then open the CSV file in Excel, which is great for looking at your data!