# Getting three dots in the CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've saved some data of mine in a csv file using pandas (from a dict) and if I'm looking at it or printing it I'm getting 3 dots in the middle of the information. I think it might be because the string is too long.

Example:

```
[-1.19583108e-02,  7.44251342e-03, -1.35046719e-02, ..., 1.01258847e-03, -4.75816538e-03,  1.09870630e-02]
```

When it should've been about 300 different numbers.

Is there any solution?

Explanation:
Let's say I have a numpy array of 300 entries (we'll call it `arr`).
I want to store this array in a csv file under the header of `test`.
So I read the csv file (using `pd.read_csv` function) and try to get this array by using: `df['test'].iloc[0]`. Now even if I'm using the commands that I was suggested in the answers - I still get dots (because I think it was saved this way). What I actually want to do is to eval this string to get an actual numpy array and use it as an array, but what I get instead is this: [image: error]

I figured the `ellipsis object` is the 3 dots I don't want to get.

Comment: You want to see the whole data in the terminal or console ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe) Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/49188960/4046632

Comment: If the dots are inside the cs file, post the code you actually use to write to the file. Ideally show [mre].

Comment: @azro
I don't want to print everything, but when I eval this code I should get an array with about 300 numbers in it, but I get the wrong array

Comment: @buran same message^

Comment: Please, provide [mre]. It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: When you put it into CSV does these 3 dots appear in the file also?

Comment: @PavanSuvarna Yes

Comment: @buran I added some information

Comment: No, you did not provide any useful information. Post your code, help us to help you.

Comment: My guess is you have  problem how you write to file in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following in the beginning of your code:

```
import sys
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```

**Edit:**

Try:

```
df.loc[df[0] != ...]
```