# How to print all columns from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been having issues with printing all columns in a csv file. The data within is set out strange in my opinion however it is not relevant.

I have been using pandas to see trends within a data csv file. I was trying to print out the data as well as showing it graphically with pandas. When I try to print the filtered variable with all the data, because the data spans across many columns with the dates at the top ( I will attach a photo of the code in terminal and the data file so it is not too confusing) it does not seem to want to print all the data.

I have tried different methods such as changing it to the list() function, trying to convert it into `.to_string` or `.to_html`, however that didn't work. In the screenshot attached it is after doing `.to_string` however it just outputs this at the start "<bound method DataFrame.to_html of" and then prints some columns dates however not the data under them

```
def region_check(region, startdate, enddate, house_type):  # region, startdate, enddate

df1 = df.loc[:, startdate:enddate]
df2 = df.loc[:, 'Region Code':'Rooms']
prop_filter = df["Property_Type"] == house_type

result = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1, join='inner').where(df2["Region"] == region).where(prop_filter) 
    
result = pd.DataFrame(result)

result.dropna(inplace=True)
print(result)  # This is where it prints the data as text. At the end of result is 
                 where I was adding .to_string/html
ave = df1.mean()
ave.plot()
plt.show()
return result
```

[Screenshot of problem with .to_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or9nw.png)

[Screenshot of problem with only printing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So0dg.png)

[Screenshot of data file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki9bp.png)

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49189503/6394617)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show all columns' names on a large pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188960/how-to-show-all-columns-names-on-a-large-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Although setting the pandas option to view all columns is one option, the printed table isn't pretty. Hence, I'll recommend the use of the tabulate package.

Method 1: Print all columns after enabling the pandas option:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

print(result)
```

Method 2: Pretty print table via using the following:

```
# !pip3 install tabulate
from tabulate import tabulate

print(tabulate(result, "keys", tablefmt="psql"))
# tablefmt options: "psql", "simple", "mixed_grid" ...
```