# How to select columns which contain non-duplicate from a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select columns which contain non-duplicate from a pandas data frame and use these columns to make up a subset data frame. For example, I have a data frame like this:

```
   x  y  z
a  1  2  3
b  1  2  2
c  1  2  3
d  4  2  3
```

The columns "x" and "z" have non-duplicate values, so I want to pick them out and create a new data frame like:

```
   x  z
a  1  3
b  1  2
c  1  3
d  4  3
```

The can be realized by the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[4,2,3]],index=['a','b','c','d'],columns=['x','y','z'])
df0 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    if df.iloc[:,i].nunique() > 1:
        df1 = df.iloc[:,i].T
        df0 = pd.concat([df0,df1],axis=1, sort=False)
```

However, there must be more simple and direct methods. What are they?

Comment: When you are saying "non-duplicate values", do you mean that the column does not cointain the same value for every row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python panda remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns)

Comment: @ClementLombard I don't think that applies here. That's removing columns based on the column names, while this is removing columns based on the values within the columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df[df.columns[(df.nunique()!=1).values]]
```

Maybe you can try this one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

Apply [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html), then remove columns where `nunique` is `1`:

```
nunique = df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
cols_to_drop = nunique[nunique == 1].index
df = df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df =df[df.columns[df.nunique()>1]]
```

assuming columns with all repeated values with give `nunique` =1 other will be more 1.
`df.columns[df.nunique()>1]` will give all columns names which fulfill the purpose

Answer (score 0):

simple one liner:

```
df0 = df.loc[:,(df.max()-df.min())!=0]
```

or even better

```
df0 = df.loc[:,(df.max()!=df.min())]
```