# Check if a Series is already in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Let´s say you have some students

```
students = [ ['Jack', 34, 'Sydeny'] ,
             ['Riti', 30, 'Delhi' ] ,
             ['Aadi', 16, 'New York'] ]
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(students, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'City'])
```

And now you receive a series like this:

```
s = pd.Series(['Riti', 30, 'Delhi'], index=['Name', 'Age', 'City'])
```

I could now use `.loc` to filter for the criteria like this:

```
filtered_dfObj = dfObj.loc[(dfObj['Name'] == s['Name']) & (dfObj['Age'] == s['Age'])]
filtered_dfObj = filtered_dfObj.loc[filtered_dfObj['City'] == s['City']]
```

But if I have a lot of columns the filter code would grow very fast. So it would be the best if there would be an option like `s.isin(dfObj)`

---

Update after 5 answers: These are all good answers - Thanks! I did not do any speedtests between the different approches yet. I personally go with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56527590/940592), because it is most-flexible regarding column-selection (if it is needed).

Comment: Can maybe help you: [python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @AlexandreB. Unfortunately this does not look promissing, because I want to check if the content of the series is existing into the `bObj` rows. There is no error with duplicated columns.

Comment: i think df.equals(s) might work.. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
# number of full duplicates (rows)
print((dfObj == s).all(axis=1).sum())
```

If you wanna check only some columns then you may add filter by column names like:

```
flt = ['Name', 'Age']
# number of partial duplicates (rows)
print((dfObj[flt] == s[flt]).all(axis=1).sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

one approach would be convert Dataframe data into list and convert series data into  list and do the compare .

```
import pandas as pd

students = [ ['Jack', 34, 'Sydeny'] ,
             ['Riti', 30, 'Delhi' ] ,
             ['Aadi', 16, 'New York'] ]
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(students, index = ['Name', 'Age', 'City'])
s = pd.Series(['Riti', 38, 'Delhi'], index=['Name', 'Age', 'City'])

if(s.values.tolist() in dfObj.values.tolist()):
    print("Series present in  Datframe ")
else:
    print("Series NOT present in  Datframe ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your hint that the series data and df data is not matching - Was copy/paste error - Edited in question

Comment: This approach works for small datasets - many thanks! However, if you want to avoid type conversion, I would tend towards one of the other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Check with

```
dfObj.apply(tuple,1).isin([tuple(s.tolist())])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use apply/lambda and check if each column (axis=1) is equal to s.

```
dfObj[dfObj.apply(lambda x: x.equals(s), axis=1)]
```

Result:

```
    Name    Age City
1   Riti    39  Delhi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the index in the original dataframe, this would work

```
df.merge(s.to_frame().T, how="inner")
```

Otherwise, you can do

```
df[np.all(df.values == s.reindex(df.columns).values, axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
 row_exists = (s == dfObj).all(axis=1).any()
```