# How can I identify duplicate name from name column in csv?

Tags: python, csv

How can import a csv file and identify duplicate value in a column? I have to compare each name with other all the names in the same column and identify if there are any duplicate records.

```py
fruits_name_field_num1 = 0
fruits_name_field_num2 = 0

#from collections import Counter 

rowCount = 0 
fruits_name1 = ''
save_fruits_name1 = ''

for line in readRecord: 
    rowCount += 1 
    row_number = str(rowCount)
    print(rowCount) 
    save_fruits_name = fruits_name
    fruits_name = (str(line[fruits_name_field_num])) 
    save_fruits_name = fruits_name 
    if fruits_name == save_fruits_name: 
        print('same_fruits_name') 
    else: 
        print('different_fruits_name')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Could you please post some of your code, as well as your desired output?

Comment: fruits_name_field_num1 = 0
fruits_name_field_num2 = 0#from collections import Counter
    rowCount = 0
    fruits_name1 = ''
    save_fruits_name1 = ''

    for line in readRecord:
        rowCount += 1


        row_number = str(rowCount)
        #print(rowCount)
        #save_fruits_name = fruits_name
        fruits_name = (str(line[fruits_name_field_num]))
        save_fruits_name = fruits_name

        if fruits_name == save_fruits_name:

           print('same_fruits_name')

        else:
            print('different_fruits_name')

Comment: This is the mock code. I can't share anything from my project. However, the idea is same. I don't want the same fruits name twice.

Comment: post the code in your question please.

Comment: Well, first of all don't import as Dict, import as list and you should have a first row to be your headers. From here you should be able to identify the duplicate column names and act accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with Pandas. Example:

if you have a data frame that looks like:

```
       a      b
0    Bob  Sarah
1   Rick  Sarah
2  Steve   Rick
3    Bob   Matt
4    Ben    Ben
5  Steve    Bob
```

and you want to just find the duplicate names that appear in column 'a' of this df. You can do:

```
df_duplicates = df[df.duplicated('a')]['a']
print(df_duplicates)
```

Which outputs:

```
3      Bob
5    Steve
```

full code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')
print(df)
df_duplicates = df[df.duplicated('a')]['a']
print(df_duplicates)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to identify the duplicate column names, the simplest way to do it is one line:

```py
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

`df.columns.duplicated()` returns a boolean mask that is `True` for every column that is duplicated (so not the first occurrence, but all subsequent ones). The tilda (`~`) inverses the boolean mask, such that it's `True` only for the first occurrence of each. Finally the `.loc[]` selects only those occurences where the mask is `True`.

---

If *within a column* you want to see which values occur multiple times, you can use:

```py
dupes = {}
for col in df.columns:
    dupes[col] = df.duplicated(subset=col)
```

Comment: Thanks. However my question was how can I prevent printing

Comment: Thanks. However my question was how can I prevent printing  a     
0    Bob 
1   Rick  
2  Steve   
3    Bob   
4    Ben    
5  Steve   
From here Bob and Steve will  display one time. there will be no duplicate. I can't import pandas it's showing me error. I am working with pycharm. thanks