# How to merge two df with some change in column Name and Column number

Tags: python, pandas

## df1

```
    A   B   C   D
0  26   39  7   44
```

## df2

```
    C   D   G   H
0   12  40  26  64

pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Please do not suggest joins as this column are dynamic
desired output looks like this

```
     A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
0   26  39   7   44 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN  12   40  26  64 NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need if there is more rows with same `RangeIndex`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I am geting  this error :raise ValueError("Plan shapes are not aligned")

Comment: @RahulGambhava - I think problem is duplicated columns names, can you check it? `print (df1.columns[df1.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])` and `print (df2.columns[df2.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])`

Comment: I am using this to remove duplicated columns : list(dict.fromkeys(columnlist))

Comment: @RahulGambhava - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435354)