# Removing duplicate columns with same column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So the problem is the following. I have dataframe:

```
   a  a  b  a  b
0  0  1  2  1  2
1  3  4  5  4  5
```

For each column name, I want to remove it's duplicate columns. It is difficult to explain. The resulting dataframe should be:

```
   a  a  b
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
```

I have achived with drop_duplicates() with the transpose of df[['column_namee']] for each column, but its too slow.

I am wondering if there is any fastest way to solve it.

Comment: Somewhat related: do you have to use duplicate column names? That needlessly complicates subsequent analysis.

Comment: Check out kalu's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32961145

Comment: Why do you have duplicate columns?

Comment: your resulting dataframe still has two columns named `a`.

Comment: Yes. the column names are in real string dates ('2020-02-03') and I want to remove the the duplicate columns of the same date. Thats the reason why I want duplicate columns

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df=df.loc[:,~(df.T.duplicated()&df.columns.duplicated())]
Out[184]: 
   a  a  b
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
```

Comment: Thats actually no working if a and b have the same columns value