# Convert dataframe column with type "object" to a set()

Tags: python, pandas, set

Got a dataframe df with a column "Id"

```
     Id
0    -KkJz3CoJNM
1    08QMXEQbEWw
2    0ANuuVrIWJw
3    0pPU8CtwXTo
4    1-wYH2LEcmk
```

I need to convert column "Id" into a set() but

```
set_id = set(df["Id"])
print(set_id)
```

returns

```
{'Id'}
```

instead of a set() of the strings from column "Id"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me working correctly if exist only one `id` column:

```
set_id = set(df["Id"])
print(set_id)
{'1-wYH2LEcmk', '08QMXEQbEWw', '0pPU8CtwXTo', '0ANuuVrIWJw', '-KkJz3CoJNM'}
```

But if there is more columns names `id` then `df['id']` return `DataFrame`, so `set(df["Id"])` return unique columns names:

```
#test for 2 columns with sample data
df = pd.concat([df, df], axis=1)
print (df["Id"])
            Id           Id
0  -KkJz3CoJNM  -KkJz3CoJNM
1  08QMXEQbEWw  08QMXEQbEWw
2  0ANuuVrIWJw  0ANuuVrIWJw
3  0pPU8CtwXTo  0pPU8CtwXTo
4  1-wYH2LEcmk  1-wYH2LEcmk

set_id = set(df["Id"])
print(set_id)
{'Id'}
```

Because:

```
L = list(df["Id"])
print(L)
['Id', 'Id']
```

working same like

```
L = list(df["Id"].columns)
print(L)
['Id', 'Id']
```

and similar for sets:

```
set_id = set(df["Id"].columns)
print(set_id)
{'Id'}
```

Possible solution for deduplicate columns:

```
c = df.columns.to_series()

df.columns += c.groupby(c).cumcount().astype(str).radd('.').replace('.0','')
print (df)
            Id         Id.1
0  -KkJz3CoJNM  -KkJz3CoJNM
1  08QMXEQbEWw  08QMXEQbEWw
2  0ANuuVrIWJw  0ANuuVrIWJw
3  0pPU8CtwXTo  0pPU8CtwXTo
4  1-wYH2LEcmk  1-wYH2LEcmk
```

Or if always same values remove duplicated columns:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
print (df)
            Id
0  -KkJz3CoJNM
1  08QMXEQbEWw
2  0ANuuVrIWJw
3  0pPU8CtwXTo
4  1-wYH2LEcmk
```

Comment: I do have "Id" twice for some odd reason. But df = df.drop_duplicates() does not work somehow? Still twice "Id"?

Comment: @Vega - Then is necessary `df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]`.

Comment: Your solution seems to work but how can .drop_duplicates() not work? Isn't that the exact usecase for this?

Comment: @Vega - I think you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns)

Comment: That thread does not explain why "drop_duplicates()" does not work?

Comment: @Vega - OK, It working if transpose - like `df = df.T.drop_duplicates().T` - Because be default pandas remove duplicates by rows, not by columns.

Comment: @Vega - Because not exist like `df = df.drop_duplicates(axis=1)`