# Removing columns in Pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

I work on a big Python dataframe and notice that some columns have same values for each row **BUT** columns' names are different.
Also, some values are text, or timeseries data.

Any easy was to get rid of these columns duplicates and keep first each time?

Many thanks

Comment: are the values are partially duplicated or completely duplicated?

Comment: completely as far as i can see (300 000 rows), including the format

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post your attempted code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Let create a dummy data frame, where two columns with different names are duplicate.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':[1,2,3,'b',5,6],
    'col2':[11,'a',13,14,15,16],
    'col3':[1,2,3,'b',5,6],
     
     })

    col1    col2    col3
0   1       11      1
1   2       a       2
2   3       13      3
3   b       14      b
4   5       15      5
5   6       16      6
```

To remove duplicate columns, first, take transpose, then apply drop_duplicate and again take transpose

```
df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

result

```
    col1    col2
0   1       11
1   2       a
2   3       13
3   b       14
4   5       15
5   6       16
```

Comment: thanks Talha, no need to place an inplace=true somehwere to definitely modifiy the original df?

Comment: yes, you can place it, if you want to replace the original df instead of creating a new one

Comment: where exactly can i place it?

Comment: `df.T.drop_duplicates(inplace=True).T`