# a dataframe with several columns having the same column name, how to only keep the first and drop the rest?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename, drop

I have a df with these columns:

```
Index(['Instrument', 'Date', 'Return on Invst Cap', 'Date',
       'Book Value Per Share, Total Equity', 'Date',
       'Earnings Per Share Reported - Actual', 'Date',
       'Revenue from Business Activities - Total', 'Date',
       'Free Cash Flow - Actual', 'Date', 'Total Long Term Debt', 'Date',
       'Profit/(Loss) - Starting Line - Cash Flow'],
      dtype='object')
```

There are several columns called 'Date', some of these columns have the same values, some don't.

I would like to only keep the first "Date" column and drop the rest. I think one important step is to change the first "Date" to a different name for example to "1 Date" and drop the other "Date" column

But I failed to rename just this column. For example I tried `df_big5_simplified= df_big5.rename(columns={1: '1 Date'})` to try to rename by column index position

but the generated df is exactly the same...

I also tried this apparoach:

```
columns=pd.Index(['Date', 'Instrument', 'Return on Invst Cap',
       'Book Value Per Share, Total Equity',
       'Earnings Per Share Reported - Actual',
       'Revenue from Business Activities - Total', 'Free Cash Flow - Actual',
       'Total Long Term Debt', 'Profit/(Loss) - Starting Line - Cash Flow'], name='item')

df_big5_simplifed=df_big5.reindex(columns=columns)
```

then I had this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Any ideas? I could have 50 columns called the same and only want to keep the first one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns)

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Thanks, I also wish to understand why I can't rename the 2nd column by index...

Comment: Rename by location: df.rename(columns={ df.columns[2]: "keep_date" }, inplace = True)

Comment: @gtomer Thanks, I tried your code but it has replaced every column called "Date", it's weird, do you know why my line df_big5_simplified= df_big5.rename(columns={1: '1 Date'}) doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can set all the columns names:

```
df = df.set_axis(['Instrument', 'Date', 'Return on Invst Cap', 'Date2',
       'Book Value Per Share, Total Equity', 'Date3',
       'Earnings Per Share Reported - Actual', 'Date4',
       'Revenue from Business Activities - Total', 'Date5',
       'Free Cash Flow - Actual', 'Date6', 'Total Long Term Debt', 'Date7',
       'Profit/(Loss) - Starting Line - Cash Flow'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Comment: thanks, but I wish to avoid doing it manually, would be great to be able to rename the first one and then drop the other ones

Comment: Rename by location: df.rename(columns={ df.columns[2]: "keep_date" }, inplace = True)

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but it has replaced every column called "Date", it's weird, do you know why my line df_big5_simplified= df_big5.rename(columns={1: '1 Date'}) doesn't work?

Comment: df.rename(columns={ df.columns[2]: "keep_date" }, inplace = True) - this did not work?

Comment: correct, as I said, it has replaced every column initially called "Date"

Comment: Strange. it should replace only column 2