# Unique columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of dimensions `(20000,3000)` and I would there are some duplicated columns but they have different headings. How would I remove those duplicates but keep the original columns in pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns). There are also solutions that do not depend on the column names, but only on the values (what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to following to remove duplicated columns according to their values:

```
df=df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

like below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'A': [2, 4, 8, 0],
            'B': [2, 0, 0, 0],
            'B_duplicated': [2, 0, 0, 0],
            'C': [10, 2, 1, 8]})

df = df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

This would result in:

```
A  B   C
0  2  2  10
1  4  0   2
2  8  0   1
3  0  0   8
```