# How to remove duplicate columns in Python Polars?

Tags: python, duplicates, python-polars

In pandas, you can do this by:

`df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]`

`df.columns.duplicated()` returns a boolean array that denotes duplicate columns

[python pandas remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns)

Comment: Do you mean duplicated column names?

They are not possible in polars. If you create a DataFrame with duplicate column names, you will get an error.

Comment: d'oh! thanks. actually I guess it silently drops the first duplicate column? which sort of achieves the no duplicates

Comment: I don't know how you materialized the DataFrame in the first place, but it may be that you overwrote the duplicates? In any case, no need to remove duplicate names. ;)

Comment: They actually come from a `pd.read_sql().` So I was wondering how to make it work with ConnectorX and Polars, but ConnectorX does not support downloading dups either so no worries

Answer (score -1):

give this a try, see if it's what you wanted

```
df.unique()
```

https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unique.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).