# Python pandas - impossible to delete duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with duplicates that are only in the column named "file". I wrote the following line:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding='utf-8', sep=',')
df.drop_duplicates(subset="Fichier",keep='first',inplace=True)
```

But it doesn't work. I even tried to do it via Excell but it doesn't work either..

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can visit on [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it works for me :

```
#In my case
metadata = pd.read_csv('CSV/data_full.csv', low_memory=False)

myresult = pd.Series(metadata.index, index=metadata['Fichier']).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand what is metadata? I have a csv file.

Comment: for sure, my bad, I will eidt my post

Comment: Thank you but it don't work, i don't know why

Comment: Your column name is file or Fichier ?

Comment: The name of my column is Fichier