# Combine multiple CSV files using merge while retaining filename information

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

Several questions have been asked and answered similar to mine, however they all used `pd.concat`, whereas I would like to use `merge` or something that could give me similar results.

I would like to combine multiple CSV files into one master df. All my CSV files have the same two columns ("gene" and "log2foldchange").

My CSV files all look something like the following:

| gene | log2foldchange |
| --- | --- |
| gene1 | 0.03 |
| gene2 | 0.02 |
| gene3 | 0.01 |
| gene4 | 0.05 |

Each CSV file:

- has the exact same 4 genes and column names
- has a different name (obviously)

I would like to incorporate the name of the CSV file as the column name that stores the log2foldchange value so that I know where the data came from. I would like my final master df to look something like the following:

| left | name_of_1st_CSV_file | name_of_2nd_CSV_file | name_of_3rd_CSV_file | name_of_4th_CSV_file |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gene1 | 0.08 | 0.09 | 0.07 | 0.01 |
| gene2 | 0.07 | 0.03 | 0.06 | 0.001 |
| gene3 | 0.08 | 0.06 | 0.05 | 0.2 |
| gene4 | 0.09 | 0.02 | 0.03 | 0.011 |

I am able to successfully use `pd.concat` to combine all my CSV files into one master df, however, the structure of my final df is such that all the CSV files were just stacked on top of one another. This structure doesn't make sense for the type of analysis I am trying to do. I would like to use `merge`, but the issue that I am running into is that it requires **two** objects and I am not sure how to get around that.

Also I have only been able to get the file names as their own separate column, not as the column name for the log2fold change as I would like it.

This is the code that I have using pd.concat:

```
source_files = sorted(Path('path/to/my/files').glob('*.csv'))

dataframes = []
for file in source_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file) 
    df['source'] = file.name
    dataframes.append(df)

df_all = pd.concat(dataframes)
display(df_all)
```

This results in a df that looks like this:

| gene | log2foldchange | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gene1 | 0.03 | 1st CSV file |
| gene2 | 0.02 | 1st CSV file |
| gene3 | 0.01 | 1st CSV file |
| gene4 | 0.04 | 1st CSV file |
| gene1 | 0.05 | 2nd CSV file |
| gene2 | 0.06 | 2nd CSV file |

etc...

This is the code I have using pd.merge that results in an error because only one object is given:

```
path = 'path/to/my/files'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) #make list of file paths 

#initialize empty data frame 
li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.merge(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
display(frame)
```

Comment: pd.concat would work as desired provided you renamed the column of the values beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED: Tweaked in response to comments**

Would this work?

```
from functools import reduce

list_of_dfs = []

for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0, sep=",") #Change sep to whatever separates your data
    df = df.loc[:, ['gene', 'log2foldchange']] #Subset out only the two columns you want
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0] #Get filename without extension
    df = df.rename(columns={'log2foldchange': file_name}) #Rename log2fold column with file name
    list_of_dfs.append(df) #Add df to list of dfs

df_merged = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='gene',how='outer'), list_of_dfs)
```

Comment: You could probably forego the "outer" option. I like leaving it in to catch any typos in my datasets e.g. there's a "gene_4" instead of "gene4". If you're confident that your datasets won't have this problem, feel free to leave that bit out :)

Comment: This resulted in: KeyError: 'gene'.

Comment: Is the column header in your csv file "gene" like in the example?

Comment: Yes it is. I just went through and had all the column names of my files printed as a list and they all had 'gene'. The only thing that is different is that my files all have an extra column called 'Unnamed: 0' which I was unaware of as it doesn't appear when I open each CSV file.

Comment: Hmmm.. a quandary. The error is basically sayin that it can't find 'gene' in the headers of the csv files, so let's just troubleshoot that. If you just load up a single csv file to a pandas df, are the columns then "Unnamed: 0", "gene" and "log2foldchange"? And just to cover my bases, there isn't a whitespace in the headers?

Comment: Correct! I printed the column names as a list for one of the files and it printed the following: List of column names :  ['Unnamed: 0', 'gene', 'log2.fold_change.']. Ill make an edit to my question and add a photo of what the df looks like for a single file.

Comment: Just got it to work! Was a simple syntax error on my end. Thanks!

Comment: So it worked in that it combined all of my df's in the structure that I wanted, but it did not re-name each column with the file name.

Comment: These are the column names for the merged df:List of column names :  ['Unnamed: 0_x', 'gene', 'log2.fold_change._x', 'Unnamed: 0_y', 'log2.fold_change._y', 'Unnamed: 0_x', 'log2.fold_change._x', 'Unnamed: 0_y', 'log2.fold_change._y', 'Unnamed: 0_x', 'log2.fold_change._x', 'Unnamed: 0_y', 'log2.fold_change._y'].  I can go through and remove the "unnamed" columns but the others should have been the file name.

Comment: Also I get the following error: /var/folders/mp/skj2cv1x2fn5t41rw38q0bw80000gn/T/ipykernel_33140/3503650697.py:11: FutureWarning: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns {'Unnamed: 0_x', 'log2.fold_change._x'} in the result is deprecated and will raise a MergeError in a future version.
  df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['gene'],how='outer'), list_of_dfs)

Comment: Ah - ya, I forgot about the renaming of the columns with the file names. I've gotta hop into a meeting but I'll have another run at it a bit later to sort that out :)

Comment: Code updated :)

Comment: worked beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the accepted answer because it does the job. However, in this answer:

- About your problem,
- A quick fix,
- An efficient alternative

---

**About discarding `concat`**

It seems you take that decision **for the wrong reasons**. According to you, the problems are:

1. you get dataframes on top of each other
2. you get file source as extra column but instead would like it as data column name

This is why I felt compelled to write another answer as the accepted one. Because this is in fact no `.concat` problem:

1. You seem to ignore that `pd.concat` with `axis=1`: exist. The default `axis=0` indeed would pile up dataframes vertically.
2. Keeping track of the file source as a new column was a good idea. But what you want here instead, is to directly rename the column holding the data. You are doing it eventually, so why not skip the extra temporary column?

---

**Quick fix**

This is your earlier code, modified as little as possible to take these two points into account:

```
# 1. List files to read
source_files = glob.glob('yourpath\*.csv')

# 2. Convert list of files into list of dataframes
dataframes = []
for filename in source_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename) 
    df.rename(columns={'log2foldchange' : filename}, inplace=True)
    dataframes.append(df)

# 3. Concatenate it
df = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
```

With an additional step, remove the duplicate 'gene' column:

```
    left  name_of_1st_CSV_file   left  name_of_2nd_CSV_file   left  name_of_3rd_CSV_file   left  name_of_4th_CSV_file
0  gene1                  0.08  gene1                  0.09  gene1                  0.07  gene1                 0.010
1  gene2                  0.07  gene2                  0.03  gene2                  0.06  gene2                 0.001
2  gene3                  0.08  gene3                  0.06  gene3                  0.05  gene3                 0.200
3  gene4                  0.09  gene4                  0.02  gene4                  0.03  gene4                 0.011
```

Since you specify they are identical, we can just drop them by identical names as in [python pandas remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14984119/12846804)

```
df_all = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]

    left  name_of_1st_CSV_file  name_of_2nd_CSV_file  name_of_3rd_CSV_file  name_of_4th_CSV_file
0  gene1                  0.08                  0.09                  0.07                 0.010
1  gene2                  0.07                  0.03                  0.06                 0.001
2  gene3                  0.08                  0.06                  0.05                 0.200
3  gene4                  0.09                  0.02                  0.03                 0.011
```

That's for `concat` not being the issue.

---

**Preferred solution**

Now for sake of efficiency, you have to know that for large file numbers, a `list.append` at each `for` loop iteration becomes inefficient compared to a list comprehension. Recommended reading on the subject: [Are list-comprehensions and functional functions faster than "for loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22108488/12846804)

Consider this same code as the above *quick fix* just rewritten to be more efficient:

```
# 1. This is your pre-processing. Shape the unit dataframes for aggregation.
def csv_to_df(filename):
    '''convert file path to unit dataframe'''
    df = pd.read_csv(filename) 
    return df.rename(columns={'log2foldchange' : filename})

# 2. concat works naturally
df = pd.concat([csv_to_df(file) for file in source_files], axis=1))
df_all = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

Same output:

```py
    left name_of_1st_CSV_file name_of_2nd_CSV_file name_of_3rd_CSV_file name_of_4th_CSV_file
0  gene1                 0.08                 0.09                 0.07                 0.01
1  gene2                 0.07                 0.03                 0.06                0.001
2  gene3                 0.08                 0.06                 0.05                  0.2
3  gene4                 0.09                 0.02                 0.03                0.011
```